# What is the best way to select sub-class to instantiate at compile time via #define

Tags: c++, arduino

I currently have an IoT gadget that has different Display subclasses depending on what hardware I am compiling for.  There is a base class called Display and have various subclasses like D_oled32 and D_oled64.  At compile time I set a build flag via #define so that when I instantiate the the Display object it will pick the specified subclass.  The way I have it now does work but VSCode is confused by it and I don't know if there is a more elegant way of doing it.  Currently I do this :
[image]

```
#if defined(MAX7219)
    #include "Displays/D_max7219.h"
    #define DISPLAY_CLASS D_max7219
#elif defined(EPD)
    #include "Displays/epdfeather.h"
    #define DISPLAY_CLASS D_epdfeather
#elif defined(OLED32)
    #include "Displays/D_oledy32.h"
    #define DISPLAY_CLASS D_oledy32
#elif defined(OLED64)
    #include "Displays/D_oledy64.h"
    #define DISPLAY_CLASS D_oledy64
#elif defined(CHA)
    #include "Displays/ledfeather.h"
    #define DISPLAY_CLASS D_ledfeather
#endif
Display *display;
```

Then in setup I do :

```
    // setup the display object
    // display hardware is specified at compile time
    display = new DISPLAY_CLASS(config);    // DISPLAY_CLASS is SET in a #define at the top of this file
```

Comment: Well I managed to de-confuse VSCode but putting in a default #else case in the define block ```#else
 #include "Displays/D_ledfeather.h"
 #define DISPLAY_CLASS D_ledfeather 
#endif```

Comment: Don't create MACRO for type, use typedef instead: `using DISPLAY_CLASS = D_ledfeather;`

Comment: So I got it working with "using" syntax like this :
#else
 #include "Displays/D_ledfeather.h"
 using DisplaySubClass = D_ledfeather;
#endif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not "define" a type but use `using` to set an alias for a type:

```
#if defined(MAX7219)
  #include "Displays/D_max7219.h"
  using DISPLAY_CLASS = D_max7219;
#elif defined(EPD)
  #include "Displays/epdfeather.h"
  using DISPLAY_CLASS = D_epdfeather;
#elif defined(OLED32)
  #include "Displays/D_oledy32.h"
  using DISPLAY_CLASS = D_oledy32;
#elif defined(OLED64)
  #include "Displays/D_oledy64.h"
  using DISPLAY_CLASS = D_oledy64;
#elif defined(CHA)
  #include "Displays/ledfeather.h"
  using DISPLAY_CLASS = D_ledfeather;
#endif
Display *display = new DISPLAY_CLASS(config);
```